# Why data sent by JSON are not displayed correctly in table?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, handsontable

I have a problem with displaying my JSON in table correctly. I am using handsontable to built a grid on website. As I think, all I need to do is to send the data in correct JSON format to handsontable [link](http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html).

I am using struts2-json-plugin to serialize Java object to JSON format and this JSON below is generated by the plugin automatically.

Unfortunatelly after send JSON to handsontable, in the table there are only values like `[object Object]` which occurs in the first cell of table only, instead of real values which should appear in whole row (in different columns), not only in the first cell...

- **Screenshot with my wrong table columns and values:**

[image]

- **Screenshot with expected table columns and values:**

[image]

I am sending JSON from backend like this:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "fieldDTO": [
        {
          "value": "Elda"
        },
        {
          "value": "HCPP"
        },
        {
          "value": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "value": "Green"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "headers": [
    "Name",
    "Qualification",
    "Certification",
    "Classification"
  ],
  "rows": [
    "Albania"
  ]
};
```

Displaying table like this:

```html
<div id="spreadsheet"></div>
$("#spreadsheet").handsontable({
  startRows: 4,
  startCols: 20,
  rowHeaders: data.rows,
  colHeaders: data.headers,
  data: data.values,
  contextMenu: true,
  width: 1000,
  manualColumnResize: true,
  manualColumnMove: true,
  columnSorting: true
});
```

FIDDLE:
You can check it in FIDDLE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2VgSR/).

Why it fails? Is my JSON format incorrect to display data in each column? I need to display List of collection FieldDTO in one row, so that's why the JSON has form as above. How to make this code (displaying data in table) to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `columns` attribute in the `handontable` called in order to dig into your (slightly strange, see below) data structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwu2E/

```
$("#spreadsheet").handsontable({
  // etc...
  columns: [
    { data: "fieldDTO.0.value" }, 
    { data: "fieldDTO.1.value" }, 
    { data: "fieldDTO.2.value" },
    { data: "fieldDTO.3.value" }
  ]
});
```

[See the docs for the array syntax for more info](http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html#array-hidden).

I say "strange" because it would be a lot nicer to have appropriately-named columns in an object instead of in an array. Position-based structures are brittle.

Comment: Ok, as you said I can't do this in this way. I've started implementation like this because I need to display in each table row: the **list of objects** but not only **one object** per row. So, in my situation I have a list of objects with one property `value` to display, instead of one object with multiple properties which properties could be mapped to columns. That's why I need to look for some idea how to do it correctly.. Do you have some idea?

Comment: @Roman You can do almost any sort of column mapping you need to by referring to the docs I linked to. The data you return needs to be row-based, but using nested objects, and indexing into them, appears trivial.